# The MVN build status isn't setting properly or re-running will not rewrite the status

Tags: bash, maven, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I am running some tests through mvn test & I am re-running failed tests again like below. I am running this in bash task in release pipeline.

```
mvn test (runs all the tests)

if failed
   mvn test (runs only failed tests)
```

If first time any tests failure then the build status will be as failed and After re-running the tests, even though command is success still pipeline status of the task is fail.

Any way we can update the status in release pipeline based on flag value ?

Updated Answer : with help of below command , getting status of previously executed statement I was able to get the status and manually exited the bash with exit 0 or exit 1 based on the flag value

```
[[ $? -ne 0 ]] && FLAG=true || FLAG=false
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

with help of below command , getting status of previously executed statement I was able to get the status and manually exited the bash with exit 0 or exit 1 based on the flag value

```
[[ $? -ne 0 ]] && FLAG=true || FLAG=false
```